# Unable to access a disk with whitespace in its name

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I am trying to access a dataset stored in a disk that is mounted in Linux. The disk's name is 'New Volume'. Python gives me an Error,
`[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I tried keeping the dataset in the tmp folder and I was successfully able to load the data. If the data is in 'New Volume', I am unable to access it but I can successfully navigate to the particular folder through command line.

This is my code:

```
train_horse_dir = os.path.join("/media/visheshchanana/New\ Volume/horse-or-human/horses")
```

Even tried this:

```
train_horse_dir = os.path.join("//media//visheshchanana//New\ Volume//horse-or-human//horses")
```

The following works:

```
train_horse_dir = os.path.join("/tmp/horse-or-human/horses")
```

Comment: You are overthinking it. Just use the filename you want without adding any backslashes in front of the spaces

Comment: And in general, `os.path.join()` works by joining *multiple arguments* into one path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check python document for [os.path.join(path, *paths)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html), it has 2 arguments with a "," in between, thus you can join the two paths.

For your case, no need to use the function.

the problem in your path with space, please don't add any "\" or "/", just use space within the "complete path" e.g. (Hereby "DVD Player" with space inside ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
youDatasetPATH = "/Volumes/MacOSx/Applications/DVD Player.app/Contents/MacOS"
print(os.listdir(youDatasetPATH))
```